JFrog REST API to Export the X-ray SBOM report
I have created the following call to export the JFrog X-ray SBOM data
curl -u $USER_NAME:$API_KEY -X POST $ARTIFACT_DOMAIN_URL/xray/api/v1/component/exportDetails \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-o "test.json" \
-d '{
    "component_name": "docker://test-docker-image:latest",
    "package_type": "docker",
    "sha_256": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "violations": true,
    "include_ignored_violations": false,
    "license": true,
    "exclude_unknown": false,
    "security": true,
    "malicious_code": false,
    "iac": false,
    "services": false,
    "applications": false,
    "output_format": "json",
    "spdx": false,
    "cyclonedx": true,
    "cyclonedx_format": "json",
    "vex": false,
    "operational_risk": false
}'


The output is written on the test.json file, but it is in the binary format and I couldn't read it and also couldn't see the results on the terminal.
If I try to see the output on the terminal, I am getting the following waring message
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.

If anyone knows the solution for this or any other method except from UI to export the X-ray SBOM data, please let me know.

The JFrog REST-API export component details is exporting a zip file (thus a binary file) inside it you'll have all the files that you set as true (In your case cyclonedx)

"Hello, as Dor Tambour has mentioned, you should modify the output file option from -o "test.json" to -o "test.zip". Additionally, you have the option to change the output_format to PDF, as detailed in the JFrog Xray documentation: https://jfrog.com/help/r/xray-rest-apis/export-component-details-v2.
I also encountered similar issues when trying to export my SBOM files. Using this approach, I was able to obtain the SBOM exactly as it appears when downloaded directly from the Artifactory UI.
Cheers, Roy"
